# Disable Window resize Animation on Android

Tags: android, animation, resize, window

I have an Activity whose size doesn't fill the whole screen. Its background is dimmed. I want to go into fullscreen with the click of a button. It works fine playing with the Window LayoutParams. But during the resize an Animation I want to get rid off occurs.

Using [Window.setWindowAnimations(int resId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setWindowAnimations%28int%29) only affects the Animation when the Window appears or disappears, not when it resizes. How can I modify this Animation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```